# How to correctly handle forms through "smart" URL

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm currently working on a private project to help me get the hang of smarty and working with SEO friendly URLS.

i've developed something that is similar to a MVC type application where everything is routed through the *index* of the website example:

```
/*
    Display The Page which is located in the first element of the new array 
*/
$Views->Display_Page($Parameters[0]);
```

With the above example, My current URL structure is:

> 127.0.0.1/SPT/Register

broken down:

> 127.0.0.1 = web address
>
> SPT = Sub Directory
>
> Register = Page to be displayed.

*How pages are displayed*

I'm using a method based structure within my `$Views` variable, which runs as so:

```
public function Display_Page($PageName){
    /*
        This is the main call from the index page:
            Index.php -> $Parameters[0] will server as the page name.

        This function will check if there is a method which will act as the outer core for the Framework.
            If Method is detected, then display the page by appending .tpl to the end of the variable passed
            if Method is not detected, then display a 404 page
    */
        if (!method_exists($this,$PageName)){
            $this->_Instance->assign("css",$this->DirectoryStructure()."/Templates/Fluid_New/CSS/css404.css");
            $this->_Instance->display("404.html");
            exit;
        }
        call_user_func(array($this, $PageName),$PageName);
        $this->_Instance->display($PageName.".tpl");
    }
}
```

So pages are being displayed if a method inside `$views` is created, otherwise show a 404 page..

Now, within this structure, i'm faced with the problem of handling multiple forms all being posted to the index page..

How would I go about handling different forms depending on the content from `$_POST`?

Comment: What's exactly the problem..multiple forms on the same page or submitting the forms to the right page?

Comment: @redreggae Little bit of a weird thing, all `$_POST` variables will be worked with and routed through index, so it's a matter of submitting the right forms for the correct validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understood your problem but I handle multiple forms on one page with hidden fields.

```
// form 1
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1">
    ...
</form>

// form 2
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form2">
    ...
</form>

// validation/saving

if ($_POST['form'] == 'form1') {
    // do the form validation and saving stuff
}
else if ($_POST['form'] == 'form2') {
    // do the form validation and saving stuff
}
```